# error 500 as a result of deleting cron job logs

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

i deleted my cron jobs logs in my home directory of my website. i.e

wp-load.php?import_key=xxxx&import_id=33&action=trigger
wp-load.php?import_key=xxxx&import_id=33&action=processing

After deleting those logs, am now encountering the following error:

> This page is not working example.com is currently unable to handle this request.
> HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: do you have access to your server? better to look the logs that stored in the `/var/logs`

Comment: You can try re-creating the files and see if the system starts working again, giving time to investigate the actual problem.

Comment: the accumulated files were over 100,000 and they cause my website to be slow. i tried to recreate a few but still not working